# Download array of audios from Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app must download every sound that would be uploaded on Firebase Storage. To do so, I followed the next way:

1) all sounds in Firebase Storage should be named from 1 to n (1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3...n.mp3).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQU4N.png)

2) After that, it creates ArrayList of tempfiles. The sounds from Firebase Storage will be uploaded right into them.

```
private int howmuch = 4;

ArrayList<File> music = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<StorageReference> url = new ArrayList<StorageReference>();
    try {
        for(int i=1; i <= howmuch; i++){
        music.add(File.createTempFile("qqqq"+i, "mp3"));}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int j=1; j <= howmuch; j++){
        url.add(FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://engapp-c0f2e.appspot.com/beginner/"+j+".mp3"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < howmuch; i++){
    url.get(i).getFile(music.get(i)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Successfully downloaded data to local file
            // ...
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle failed download
            // ...
            Log.w(TAG, "Failure");
        }
    });
```

Variable **howmuch** returns a positive integer, this is a number of sounds that need to be exactly downloaded and a number of temp files need to be created. Clearly, their numbers have to be equaled. It could be as 4, as 10, as 100.

ArrayList **music** contains temp files, where it puts our sounds. IDE made me wrap it to try/catch.

ArrayList **url** contains LINK to every file it needs to download. As you can see, I use *for* loop for that (it can seem weird, but I don't really know better solution).

So it works well despite the algorithm seems weak. It downloads all sounds and I can furter play it with MediaPlayer. That's how I do it:

```
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(File.separator + DBcontent.getMusic(counter));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            counter ++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**DBcontent** is an object of class where we've put our sounds to temp files from Firebase Storage. Method **getMusic()** is a typical getter

**counter** is a typical counter. From the begining **counter**=0. So we will be retrieving EVERY sound from our ArrayList and make it play.

```
public File getMusic(int a){
    File c = music.get(a);
    return c;
}
```

Now the main problem. If Firebase Storage contains less sounds than we need to download (for example **howmuch** = 10, but we have only 5 sounds in our storage) it's going to work anyway, but temp files would be empty so it can not to be played. it means, if **howmuch** was 10, and **counter** is 6, so the app would work not properly.

What exactly I need. Either the algorithm to check ArrayList of temp files for EMPTY/null and remove them afterwards or any other solution to download sounds and put them into ArrayList (or even sipmlest Array[]).

Thank you.

Comment: Node that Cloud Storage (for storing files) is not the same as Cloud Firestore (for storing/querying NoSQL data). Your code seems to only use Storage, in which case I'd remove any reference to Firestore.

Comment: Oh, yes, sure. It's typing error. Fixed it. Thank you.